# Calling from a javascript function another javascript function having return false;?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, function, return

I have this simple javascript function which calls other 2 functions:

```js
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

    function mainfunction() {
        function1()
        function2()
    }

    function function1() {
        if (//some test) {
            alert('test function1');
            return false;
        }
    }

   function function2() {
        if (//some test) {
            alert('test function2');
            return false;
        }
    }

</script>
```

i call `mainfunction()` like this:

```asp
<form id="form1" runat="server" onSubmit="return mainfunction()">
```

or like this:

```asp
<asp:Button ID="btntest" runat="server" Text="test button" OnClientClick="return mainfunction()" />
```

`btntest` is a button that just calls some class which redirects to another page.

### The problem

- if i directly call any of the 2 functions `function1()` or `function2()` then the button will not get executed, which is what i want. but...:
  When i call `mainfunction()` then alert in each function works but `return false;` doesn't seem to work because the button unfortunately gets executed.

why is that? how can i call the 2 functions and let their `return false;` work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `mainfunction` is not returning anything. Try this:

```
function mainfunction() {
    return function1() && function2();
}
```

As mentioned in the comments, to have your `mainfunction` working properly, you have to alter your other functions to always return either `true` or `false`:

```
function function1() {
    if (//some test) {
        alert('test function1');
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

**EDIT**
A funny hack to have both functions being executed and still return `true` only when both functions are `true`:

```
function mainfunction() {
    return (function1() + function2()) === 2;
}
```

Comment: `function1` returns `undefined` or `false`, not `true` or `false`. `undefined` is not truthy, so `function2` will never be called.

Comment: @icktoofay: Okay, I should have said that you have to extend your functions by returning `true`. I will fix that. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Thank you Amberlamps and icktoofay. I tried the solution: i changed mainfunction and the other 2 functions as mentioned but now unfortunately only function1 is called.

Comment: So you want to execute every function at any time? Even if the first validation already failed and you do not want to submit the form?

Comment: @Amberlamps adding a "funny hack" into an answer, read by inexperienced js users is not useful - it's just noise and a distraction. If you want to test the return values - just check for `=== false` or `!== false`.

Comment: @AD7six: I see your point. However, I will stand by my answer. It solves the issue and can be altered even by beginners accordingly.

Comment: thank you guys, now function2 is called regardless if function1 fails or not. but this made me lost a bit, I don't really understand the purpose of the hack.

Comment: also i notice that it won't work unless i call mainfunction like this: `return mainfunction()`

Comment: I thought you wanted `function2` to be called even if `function1` has failed?! If you want `function2` to be executed when `function1` is `true`, stay with my original answer. And, like you said, add `return mainfunction()` to the `onsubmit` attribute.

Comment: No as i said i need to execute both functions regardless of each return result. So the answer of the funny hack is the solution for this. Thank you for the hack so much, however i don't quite understand it i'm afraid.

Comment: @compliance: If you run an arithmetic operation on a boolean, Javascript will implicitly convert the value to an integer. `true` is `1` and `false` is `0`. So if both functions return `true`, you have `true + true` which is `1 + 1` which is `2`. So `mainfunction` will only return `true` when both functions return `true`.

Comment: Wow that was really interesting to know, thank you. Thank you too for both answers, one if i only move to function2 if first function succeeds, and the other if i want to run both functions and then check final return result.

Answer (score 0):

`mainfunction` doesn't return anything, you aren't using the return values from either `function1` or `function2`

To prevent a form from submitting, you need the handler itself to return false, for example:

```
function mainfunction() {
    function1();
    function2();

    return false; // prevent form submission
}
```

Returning undefined (what you're doing right now in the example in the question) is not sufficient.

Comment: Thank you AD7six, but the result is not always false. However thank you as I see what you mean, mainfunction didn't return anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<asp:Button ID="btntest" runat="server" Text="test button" OnClientClick="mainfunction(); return false;" />
```

This will works as well:

```
<asp:Button ID="btntest" runat="server" Text="test button" OnClientClick="return mainfunction();" />
```

but you will need to change mainfunction:

```
function mainfunction() {
    function1();
    function2();
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it made me realize that i must also use return when calling mainfunction(). however mainfunction() does not always return false.